# data and salt require by hashSync

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

i dont kwon why i am getting this issue, i check documentation and i didnt 
  find my mistake. Any idea?

**Error: data and salt arguments required**

```
 const {create} = require('./user.service');
 const {genSaltSync, hashSync} = require('bcrypt');

 module.exports ={
     createUser : (request, response)=>{
         const body = request.body;
         const salt = genSaltSync(10);
         body.password = hashSync(body.password, salt);
         create(body, (err,results)=>{
             if(err){
                 console.log(err);
                 return response.status(500).json({
                     message:"Error en la conexion"
                 }); 
             }
             return response.status(200).json({
                 data:results
             });
         });
     }
 }
```

Comment: Can you console log the body variable before create(body, (err,results)) line of code

Comment: i got an empty value

Answer (score 1):

it seems like the `body.password` is empty (null or undefined) or invalid.

**Check the `body` value with a console.log**, and make sure you have the `body.password` as a string before passing it to the hashSync function.

Comment: yeah i saw that, it seems that i have an empty value. Im gonna check my values from my services js